# ubuntu 22.04 routing using netplan

Tags: server, netplan, ip, routing, ping

Hi I have a new ubuntu server with 2 interfaces and i wrote a netpaln config for it like this:

```
network:
 version: 2
 renderer: networkd
 ethernets:
   ens160:
     dhcp4: no
     addresses:
       - 192.168.1.2/24
     routing-policy:
       - from: 192.168.1.0/24
         table: 160
     routes:
       - to:  0.0.0.0/0
         via: 192.168.1.1
       - to: 172.10.10.10
         via: 192.168.1.1
         on-link: true
         metric: 100
         table: 160
     nameservers:
       addresses:
         - 8.8.8.8
         - 4.2.2.4
     accept-ra: no
   ens192:
     dhcp4: no
     addresses:
       - 172.31.99.2/24
     routing-policy:
       - from: 172.31.99.0/24
         table: 192
     routes:
       # - to:  0.0.0.0/0
       #  via: 172.31.99.1
       - to:  172.22.22.22
         via: 172.31.99.1
         on-link: true
         metric: 100
         table: 192
     accept-ra: no
```

I have 2 questions:

1. If I uncomment the default gateway for ens192 I get this warnings :

```
** (generate:2260): WARNING **: 20:34:27.603: Problem encountered while validating default route consistency.Please set up multiple routing tables and use `routing-policy` instead.
Error: Conflicting default route declarations for IPv4 (table: main, metric: default), first declared in ens192 but also in ens160

** (process:2258): WARNING **: 20:34:28.411: Problem encountered while validating default route consistency.Please set up multiple routing tables and use `routing-policy` instead.
Error: Conflicting default route declarations for IPv4 (table: main, metric: default), first declared in ens192 but also in ens160

** (process:2258): WARNING **: 20:34:28.427: Problem encountered while validating default route consistency.Please set up multiple routing tables and use `routing-policy` instead.
Error: Conflicting default route declarations for IPv4 (table: main, metric: default), first declared in ens192 but also in ens160

** (process:2258): WARNING **: 20:34:28.970: Problem encountered while validating default route consistency.Please set up multiple routing tables and use `routing-policy` instead.
Error: Conflicting default route declarations for IPv4 (table: main, metric: default), first declared in ens192 but also in ens160

** (process:2258): WARNING **: 20:34:28.971: Problem encountered while validating default route consistency.Please set up multiple routing tables and use `routing-policy` instead.
Error: Conflicting default route declarations for IPv4 (table: main, metric: default), first declared in ens192 but also in ens160
```

why this happens?
and second question:
if I want to ping the destinations on routing table 160 or 192 no packet is transfered:

```
ping 172.20.20.20
4 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss
ping 172.20.20.20 -I ens192
4 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss
```

what is the solution?
thanks for your attention.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your default routes on each interface also need to specify the table.

And in your example, you are pinging an IP that you don't currently have a route for on ens192.